# How to increase code coverage for catch block

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, exception

I have below Apex class (DAO class) which has a try-catch block. Same try-catch block has been used in 5 different methods. I tried sending setOpportunityId as account id or null id but still, it is not going to catch block.

Class:

```
public with sharing class OppUpdateDAO {
public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunityData(set<ID> setOpportunityId) {
        try {
            List<Opportunity> opportunityList = new List<Opportunity>();
            opportunityList=[select id , name, stageName,RecordTypeId ,Market__cfrom Opportunity where id in:setOpportunityId ];
            return opportunityList;

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Error_Handling__c error = M2O_ErrorHandling.errorHandling (e);
            insert error;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, your method could just have a single line of code inside the code block: `public static Opportunity[] getOpportunityData(set<ID> setOpportunityId) { return [select name, stageName, RecordTypeId, Market__c from Opportunity where id in :setOpportunityId ]; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets analyse the code in your try block.

```
List<Opportunity> opportunityList = new List<Opportunity>();
opportunityList=[select id , name, stageName,RecordTypeId ,Market__cfrom Opportunity where id in:setOpportunityId ];
return opportunityList;
```

There is no way there can be an catchable exception that can appear in those 3 lines.

The only exception that can occur is Heap or Too many SOQL exceptions which is Limit exception that cannot be caught so catch block is useless.

Theriotically catch block will never be called, and thus I dont think you need a try catch block in the first place.

Solution : Remove the try catch.

Comment: not a QueryException 'Record Not Available' due to a long-held lock by some other transaction?

Comment: @cropredy thats a great shout, I am the dilemma if the try catch should be written for it.  That being said I never reproduced in test execution so i wonder how to cover it without test.IsRunningTest

Comment: Pranay:   Well, the way to cover it without using Test.isRunningTest is to use Selector classes and ApexMocks doThrowWhen.  But as sfdcfox so often says, for self-evident catch blocks of unusual exceptions, “why bother”.